# How to move files from a directory to another directory based on file size

Tags: vbscript, batch-file, batch-processing

I am currently working on an automation project at work. One of the steps to the program that I need to separate files that are greater than 6000KB from the other files in the folder. I am looking for a batch file that is able to move files that are greater than 6000KB from their current directory to another directory. I need this batch file to do handle a batch of files and not just one. Any thoughts on how to do this in a batch file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7363523/69820

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use VBScript, you can use this script as a basis:

```
' use a default source path or get one from the command line parameters
dim sourcepath: sourcepath = "some\default\path"
if WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("source") then
    sourcepath = WScript.Arguments.Named("source")
end if

' use a default destination path or get one from the command line
dim destinationpath: destinationpath = "some\default\path"
if WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("destination") then
    destinationpath = WScript.Arguments.Named("destination")
end if

' use a default file size limit or get one from the command line
' we accept in kbytes so we convert this to bytes
dim sizelimit: sizelimit = 6000 * 1024 ' default 6000 kbytes
if WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("sizelimit") then
    sizelimit = WScript.Arguments.Named("sizelimit")
end if

' use a Scripting.FileSystemObject to get the file objects of each file
' in the source directory. The file object has a Size property, which
' has the file size in bytes
dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim sourcefolder: set sourcefolder = fso.GetFolder(sourcepath)
if not fso.FolderExists(destinationpath) then
     ' we'll throw an error if the path is not found but you could instead
     ' create the directory automatically
     err.raise 1,,destinationpath & " not found"
end if

' loop through each file in the directory, compare size property against
' the limit and copy as appropriate
dim file, count: count = 0
for each file in sourcefolder.Files
    if file.size > sizelimit then
         file.Move destinationpath
         count = count + 1
    end if
next

WScript.Echo("complete: " & count & " file(s) moved")
```

You could run this (call it `move-files.vbs`) from a batch file thus:

```
cscript move-files.vbs /source:"C:\Documents and Settings\Username\Desktop" /destination:"F:\backup" /sizelimit:1000
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use vbs with file object: [File object reference](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/vbscript/quickref/file.html)

or you can try to make a .bat file using this command to extract the filesize.

```
for %%R in ([filepath and name]) do if %%~zR GTR [file size]
```

from this page: [Batch file to check filesize](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/showandtell/thread/771e372f-e9c7-436a-bf08-27f39aeb196a)

I would recommend the VBS options for more security.

---

EDIT: this is a batch file for moving the files. Please change the `<move file>` to a more appropriate command.

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq tokens=3,4" %%i IN (`dir /-C`) DO CALL :MOVE_FILES %%i %%j 
exit /b 0

:MOVE_FILES
if %1.==. exit /b 0
if %1 GEQ 6000000 <move file>
```

Comment: I know close to nothing about vbs. I need to be able to run this script daily on a folder for imports. It will check the file size and move ALL files that are larger than 6000 KB to a different folder because it requires a different automation.

Answer (score 2):

```
ROBOCOPY c:\From c:\To /E /MOVE /MIN:6144000  /MT:32
```

Replace "c:\From" and "c:\To" paths to your real paths to files

`/MIN:n` : MINimum file size - exclude files smaller than n bytes.

`/MT[:n]` : Multithreaded copying, n = no. of threads to use (1-128) ###
                     default = 8 threads, not compatible with /IPG and /EFSRAW
                     for Windows7

`/E` : Copy Subfolders, including Empty Subfolders.

`/S` : Copy Subfolders.

Robocopy is a Standard **Windows7** command, to use it under **Windowx XP** download and install [Microsoft Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657)

[Details and other parameters for Robocopy are here](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html)

Comment: I am currently working with windows xp so therefore this command line will not execute. I tried to download the resource kit. It is just a book or is it software? I only saw books. Never heard of it.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657   - Sorry, fixed link to Resource Kit download page also in my post. It's a software from Microsoft. Install it and then you'll be able to use robocopy command. BTW  /MT:32 parameter is not accessible in Windows XP - use "ROBOCOPY c:\From c:\To /E /MOVE /MIN:6144000"