# VBScript that Moves modified files to another folder

Tags: vbscript, move, datecreated, modified-date

Basically, I need a script to move files to another folder that have been accessed and modified.

I'm new to scripting, so this may be a simple problem, but I'm stumped.  Here's the error I'm getting:

Script: C:\Users\bmcwilliams\Desktop\pssitest.vbs

Line: 17

Char: 10

Error: File already exists

Code: 800A003A

Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

The destination folder is empty, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Below is the code I have.  It's modified from the code listed in this post:

[How to move files from a directory to another directory based on file size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030565/how-to-move-files-from-a-directory-to-another-directory-based-on-file-size)

```
' use a default source path
dim sourcepath: sourcepath = "C:\users\bmcwilliams\Desktop\TestUncompleted"

' use a default destination path
dim destinationpath: destinationpath = "C:\users\bmcwilliams\Desktop\TestCompleted"

dim fso: set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
dim sourcefolder: set sourcefolder = fso.GetFolder(sourcepath)

' loop through each file in the directory, compare size property against
' the limit and copy as appropriate
dim file, count: count = 0
for each file in sourcefolder.Files
    dim createDate: createDate = file.DateCreated
    dim modifyDate: modifyDate = file.DateLastModified
    if createDate <> modifyDate Then
         file.Move destinationpath
         count = count + 1
    end if
next

WScript.Echo("complete: " & count & " file(s) moved")
```

Any ideas?  Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the destination path for moving a file is a folder and not the full path (including the destination filename), it must have a trailing backslash:

```
destinationpath = "C:\users\bmcwilliams\Desktop\TestCompleted\"
```

Otherwise the `Move` operation would detect that the destination (the folder) already exists and would thus fail.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying to the new location but do not supply the new name of the file.  To fix the issue append a \ and the file name to the destination path.

```
file.Move destinationpath +"\" + file.name
```